# How to pass File in electron contextBridge

Tags: electron

I could not find the docs on electron contextBridge and what is done to the API arguments but obviously something is done.

This is the gist of it:

```js
// preload.js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('fileCache', {
  put (file) {
    console.log(file) // ==> {}
  }
})

// web app
window.fileCache.put(new File([], 'foo.txt'))
```

How should I pass `File` or any Blob or Buffer argument ? (making a string is not an option for performance reasons: 20+ Mb files...)

Comment: Closest ref I have found: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/spec-main/api-context-bridge-spec.ts

Comment: URL.createObjectURL(file) ==> fetch(url) works 